# Can't debug or execute python code inside venv from vscode directly (No module named...)

Tags: python, windows, powershell, debugging, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to run my python code inside a virtual environment (on windows) for a couple of weeks. I gave up for a while but now I want to debug and I can't get it to work. The problem is that my python scripts (in a virtual environment) use certain modules that have been installed in the environment, in fact, I can run the code from a cmd terminal without problems. However, when I run it from vscode directly or from another type of terminal (powershell, for example).
I get the error that it does not find the modules.
I thought that changing the default terminal in vscode might help but it doesn't.

I attach the error:

```
    (venv) PS C:\Users\sydea\Desktop\Cargadores solares\Proyecto\OCPP-1.6J-CS-I> python .\test_server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sydea\Desktop\Cargadores solares\Proyecto\OCPP-1.6J-CS-I\test_server.py", line 2, in <module>
    from aioconsole import ainput
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aioconsole'
```

Also, in the lower part of vscode where the selected interpreter is shown, the appropriate interpreter appears. I attach a picture:

[image: My vscode view]

Also I attach the list of pip packages installed in the virtual environment:
[modules installed in venv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpejK.png)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Try checking if that package is installed in the virtual environment. You may use `python -m pip list`

Comment: @kiner_shah Hello, thanks for your answer, I guess they are (although dunno how to make completely sure) since I can run the code directly from cmd without any errors, also I can execute python on terminal and import those modules without errors as well.

Comment: Can you execute them in virtual environment when opening from command line or terminal?

Comment: @kiner_shah Yes I can execute them in venv from cmd terminal. Also, all the packages I need are shown when using python -m pip list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the pic you attached for modules installed in venv. I notice that in the warning, the venv directory is not the one from your workspace.

As such, I suspect the issue is right there. Open the command pallete (`ctrl`+`shift`+`P`), type interpreter, and click on the option `Python: Select Interpreter`. Now type the path to the venv "`.\venv\scripts\python.exe`".

One done, open a new terminal and type `.venv\scripts\activate`. This should now activate the right venv. Once here, You should reinstall the required libraries if they are not there.

After that, it should work.

Comment: Ohh!! I see now what the problem was. You are right the packages were installed in another venv for some reason (I still don't know how I messed that up), I now installed the packages on the correct venv and now it's working fine. The interpreter was set correctly from the beginning. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: you may consider using the command: `path to venv\scripts\python.exe -m pip install [package]` to make sure you install your packages to the right location. Note that in the powershell terminal you would have to put any folder name which has a space with quotations like this: `d:\'python programs'\venv\scripts\python.exe -m ...`

Comment: Yep! That is how I did it this time. I will keep this in mind for future venvs creations! Thank you for your time and help!